# Can any hockey skate be baked?

Tags: equipment, inline-hockey

I read [here](https://hfboards.mandatory.com/threads/breaking-in-skates-unable-to-be-baked.2345999/)

> ANY skate can be baked; it's just that skate of a certain tier and above have materials DESIGNED to be baked. That doesn't mean that lower tier skates like yours cannot be; it's just that the overall effect/potential benefit is less because the materials do not react to heat the way that higher tiered skates do.

and the poster is an admin with almost 5000 posts so I would assume (s)he's not completely ignorant about the topic, hence my question.

Comment: I agree with the basic response on hfboards you reference that any skate can be baked.  That is a different question from whether or not a particular pair of skates should be baked.  Since baking softens the materials, there is a risk of separating the layers which will lead to premature breakdown.  I would be concerned with an older skate.  The bonding of materials deteriorates with age even if the skate is not being worn.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, I agree that asking about a specific skate is not the same as asking about _any_ hockey skate. Since nobody else is chipping in, if you feel like elaborating on your comment (maybe adding some first hand experience or some references of people who baked non-bakeable skates?) and turning it into an answer I would gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the basic premise that any skate can be baked. That is a different question from whether or not any particular pair of skates should be baked. Among my team and league mates, those who have baked skates designed to be baked have been pleased with the results.  The two who baked skates not designed to be baked were not as pleased with the results.  And one experienced premature breakdown where the boot separated from the plate.  A skate dealer told me that the bonding materials in boots begin to break down with age even when the boots are not worn regularly.  Since baking softens the materials, there is a risk of separating the layers in addition to what might be occurring with age.